Integration of affine transformation with non-singular matrix
I try to prove that the Fourier transform of an affine transformation f(Ax) with A a non-singular matrix and x a vector is equal to:
$$f(Ax) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} | \det{A} |^{-1} \mathcal{F}((A^{-1})^{T}\omega)$$
I think I need to use $$\int f(Ax) dx = |\det{A} |^{-1} \int f(y) dy $$
with $$y = Ax$$
But I don't know how I can prove this relation because the only thing that I know which is similar to this is for U -> V a diffeomorphism,$$ \int_V \mu(u) \,du = \int_U \mu(f(x)) |Jac{(f)} | \,dx $$
